# Do empty .ctor and .dtor reduce the performance?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

In the below example class `test1` don't have `ctor/dotr` and `test2` have empty `ctor` and `dtor`.

While allocating a big array of `test1` and `test2`, do empty `ctor` and `dtor` reduce the performance?

```
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class test1
{
public:

    int m_member;

    // Without ctor/dtor
};

class test2
{
public:

    int m_member;

    // Empty ctro
    test2(void)
    {
        // Nothing.
    }

    // Empty dtor
    ~test2(void)
    {
        // Nothing.
    }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Which one of these lines is faster?
    test1* t1 = new test1[500 * 1024 * 1024];
    test2* t2 = new test2[500 * 1024 * 1024];

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Edit**:
I believe testing this code is not easy, because allocating a large amount of memory affects next lines of the program and the system speed.

Comment: You'd have to measure it yourself, because the answer would depend on your compiler and the way you've configured it.

Comment: Seems like it would be an easy thing to test.  I wouldn't be surprised if a good compiler optimized empty functions away.

Comment: Actually it could be a challenge to test, but that's even more reason to test rather than ask!  It'll be educational (more so than reading our guesses.)  Consider using valgrind: http://valgrind.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have benchmarked it after inclusion of C++11 chrono functions in the code.
**The relative speed depends sensitively on the compiler optimization switches.**
When compiled with Gnu compiler without optimization (g++ -std=c++11 -O0) the allocation of test2 takes around 27 times longer to finish (~100 us vs 2700 us) on my laptop with i7 cpu (us = microseconds). In contrast to this the higher level of optimization (g++ -std=c++11 -O2) makes the allocation of test1 to take around 9 times longer than test2 allocation (~90 us vs 10 us). This varies a little bit each run. Here's the relevant piece of modified code:

```
steady_clock::time_point start1, end1, start2, end2;
start1 = steady_clock::now();
test1* t1 = new test1[500 * 1024];
end1 = steady_clock::now();

start2 = steady_clock::now();
test2* t2 = new test2[500 * 1024];
end2 = steady_clock::now();
cout<<duration_cast<microseconds>(end1 - start1).count()<<endl;
cout<<duration_cast<microseconds>(end2 - start2).count()<<endl;
```

Such large differences in allocation times are somewhat unexpected as the default ctor and dtor are assumably empty ones.

**Edit:** As suggested by Dale in the comment below I did additional benchmarks with the order of allocations switched. The `-O0` flag changes the execution time to (~15 us vs 2800 us). With `-O2` flag the execution time is (~10 us vs ~80 us). The standard deviation of times for multiple runs is relatively large but the speed order remains the same.

Comment: I suspect that this tells us more about the optimization flags than the code. I would wager that the empty version might become a struct under certain optimization conditions. +1 for enthusiasm, impressive .

Comment: @Oakdale Indeed! The main message of my answer is that it depends on sensitively optimization flags.

Comment: Same kind of result for [my slightly diff test](http://pastebin.com/qBAq4tYQ) with g++ 4.8.2 -O4 under cygwin (Windows 8). **Structure without constructor take alway almost twice the time**.

Comment: +1 for running the test!  It would also be interesting to reverse the order of the tests to see if that changes the results.

Comment: And to try placement new into a preallocated buffer -- taking malloc out of the picture altogether so the test measures only constructor time.

Comment: @DaleWilson Good idea. I updated the answer with results of switched order of allocations. I don't understand well your suggestion about preallocated buffer and elimination of malloc.

Comment: This: test2* t2 = new (buffer) test2[500 * 1024]; will call the constructors, using the preallocated buffer.

Comment: char * buffer = new char[500*1024*sizeof(test2)];  // don't measure this!

Answer (score 4):

It is unlikely -- especially since your constructors and destructors are inline so the compiler can optimize them out of existence.   That being said -- why don't you measure it rather than asking on Stack Overflow?